# How can I match the product id in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    
    match /userA/product/{productId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == productId;
    }
   
  }
  
}
```

Above code is not working, how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

The path of your security rule shall be at the level of the document, not of the collection. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#basic_readwrite_rules): "All match statements should point to documents, not collections".

So if you want to give access to the entire subcollection `/userA/product/{productId}` you need to adapt your rule as follows:

```
match /userA/product/{productId}/{docId} { // docId or any other wildcard name you want
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == productId;
}
```

---

In addition, note that [rules are not filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters).

Comment: Hello @KebriaZaman did you have the time to look at the answer?